# Can someone help fix the logic of my function?

Tags: java

What it's doing now is asking the user to enter a field number, but if the user enters a non integer it just gets stuck in a loop and doesn't respond to anything the user types. I want it to actually work, I think its something in my try/catch. Thanks

Code:

```
public static int getFieldNumberFromUser(int maxValue)throws IOException
{
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader(System.in) );
    String data;
    int fieldNumber;
    boolean isInteger;

    fieldNumber = 0;
    isInteger = false;
    while(isInteger == false)
    {
        System.out.print("Enter a field between 1 and " + maxValue + "(< zero to quit): ");
        data = br.readLine();
        try
        {
            fieldNumber = Integer.parseInt(data);
            isInteger = true;

        }
        catch(NumberFormatException nfe)
        {
            System.out.println("You did not enter a valid integer");
        }
    }
        return fieldNumber - 1;
}
```

Comment: if a non numeric value is entered what shuld be done

Comment: @ArunPJohny If its non numeric it should say you did not enter a valid integer and ask the user again. It does this but if I enter a numeric value after a non numeric value it just keeps repeating

Comment: @mbridges: I did not see anything wrong happening in your code. I ran it and it seems to work fine.

Comment: @mbridges it looks like working fine for me

Comment: Though I might simplify the code like `public static int getFieldNumberFromUser(int maxValue) throws IOException {
  BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

  do {
   System.out.print("Enter a field between 1 and " + maxValue
     + "(< zero to quit): ");
   try {
    return Integer.parseInt(br.readLine()) - 1;

   } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
    System.out.println("You did not enter a valid integer");
   }
  } while (true);
 }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the below code. It seems to work fine.

```
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader(System.in) );
    String data;
    int fieldNumber;
    boolean isInteger;

    fieldNumber = 0;
    isInteger = false;
    while(isInteger == false)
    {
        System.out.print("Enter a field between 1 and " + maxValue + "(< zero to quit): ");
        data = br.readLine();
        NumberFormatException nfe = new NumberFormatException();
        try
        {
            fieldNumber = Integer.parseInt(data);
            if(fieldNumber > maxValue)
                throw nfe;
            isInteger = true;

        }
        catch(NumberFormatException nfe2)
        {
            System.out.println("You did not enter a valid integer");
        }
    }
        return fieldNumber - 1;
```

Comment: Tried this and worked perfectly, thanks

Answer (score 1):

You need to exit out of your loop in the catch... Add a `return -1;` in your catch.

I'm not sure why you're looping